# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I tried to install tensorflow by typing this command on anaconda: `pip install tensorflow==1.2.0`. However, I get the following error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.2.0
```

Do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: What did you run before the error? Can you post the full error message?

Comment: Could you please run `conda list` and share the output to try to figure out what might be happening?ç

Comment: You are trying to install pretty old Tensorflow version, which is no longer supported. It is recommended to install latest stable version. Try `!pip install tensorflow` , which installs Tfv 2.6.0. Thanks!